# What is the constant g-phase in Apollo re-entry, and why does it not show up on the graph?

Tags: reentry, apollo-11, g-force

On the [Apollo 11 Flight Journal Day 9: Re-entry and Splashdown](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/26day9-reentry.html), it says something about the "Constant g-phase". This is what the ALSJ says:

> **Planned drag level (deceleration) during the *constant g phase: 4.00g*.**

An analysis of the Apollo 11 re-entry [shows a graph of the g-forces experienced](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/pdf/19740072963_as11-entry-analysis-19700220.pdf#page=30) during re-entry (measured after entry interface). Here's the graph for reference:

[image]

The graph shows no flat line indicating a constant g-level. **So what is this constant g-phase, and why did it not show up on the re-entry analysis? If this graph is incorrect, where can I find a correct version of the graph?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constant-g was used in backup manual control modes.

Note your quote says **planned** - the value of g the crew would fly was read up to them as part of the pad.

See the discussion in your link.

> 191:58:13 Evans: Okay, Mike. Of course, this is in the event the G&N
> and the EMS quits and you have to fly the constant-g;

Also [APOLLO EXPERIENCE REPORT - MISSION PLANNING FOR APOLLO ENTRY](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19720013191)

> Two backup trajectory-control modes are used for the Apollo entry.
> Both these modes use manual CM attitude control and are based upon
> constant-aerodynamic-load-factor (constant-g) trajectories...

> The basic control technique, using the EMS, is to control the entry trajectory to a load factor of 4g until the CM velocity is reduced below the circular orbital velocity...

> In the event of a GNCS and EMS failure, the entry is controlled to a constant-g trajectory with manual attitude control by using the g-meter and backup attitude reference as the primary displays.

It wasn't actually used.

Acronymology

- CM Command Module
- EMS Entry Monitoring System
- G&N Guidance and Navigation